# Get ReusableHTML from reusable content via Content query webpart

Tags: content-query-web-part, reusable

I'm trying to create a view of stuff from my reusable content list. Basically I am storing global links within the reusable content list.

I'm struggling with the content query webpart, because it always shows me the LINK to the item in the reusable content list - what I want it to show is the ReusableHTML Column of the specific item in the list.

I tried doing so with

`<property name="DataColumnRenames" type="string">ReusableHtml,Reuse</property>`
`<property name="CommonViewFields" type="string">ReusableHtml,Text</property>`

But somehow the CQWP doesn't display anything when using these two properties.

My reusable content list basically looks like so:

```
Title     ReusableHTML
Static 1  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
Static 2  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
```

And basically I want to display these global links via the masterpage of my site - easily editable for the end user in the reusable content list.

Anyone up for a .webpart file or could show me another tutorial, because the MS tutorial [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms497457.aspx) did not help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<PublishingWebControls:ContentByQueryWebPart
  runat="server"
  WebUrl="~sitecollection/"
  ListName="Reusable Content"
  ServerTemplate="100"
  DataMappings="Reuse:ReusableHtml,ReusableHtml,HTML;"
  DataMappingViewFields="Title,Text;ReusableHtml,HTML;"   
  ... >
</PublishingWebControls:ContentByQueryWebPart>
```