# How do I render a Reusable Content item from a page template?

Tags: page-layout, reusable, content-query-web-part

In a SharePoint publishing site, what do I need to include in my layout file to make it render the Reusable HTML from a specific item in the Reusable Content list?

Answer (score 3):

In the root of your site collection there is a list called **Reusable Content** that is used to capture reusable html. If you're editing a masterpage using designer then there isn't a simple >> Insert this reusable text capability.

Instead, insert a dataview pointing to the specific item in the list and including only the **Reusable Html** field.

Answer (score 1):

Reusable content can be used only one the Publishing page. So custom layout has to include the HTML Publishing content type.

Also pay attention that there's a bug in SP 2010 (On the current time it still exists): If you place a web part within the Page Content control where Reusable content is stored, the last one will turn into the 'a'. Check this question [Reusable content disappearing on Publishing Page](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12302/reusable-content-disappearing-on-publishing-page)

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for using an answer for a comment, but I just joined and don't think I can comment yet.

I managed to get my Resuable Content into a page layout in conjunction with this post...
[Get ReusableHTML from reusable content via Content query webpart](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3494/get-reusablehtml-from-reusable-content-via-content-query-webpart)

But my Resuable Content is HTML and when it renders it is the source of the HTML, not the parsed HTML.  Is this possible?  This post suggests not ...
[Reusable Content does not accept some HTML tags](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/7434/reusable-content-does-not-accept-some-html-tags)