# Reusable content disappearing on Publishing Page

Tags: page-layout, master-page

On the publishing site I've created a simple page with a Page Content.  I've added a web part there and then I'm trying to add a Reusable Content. However it turns into `a` [like here](http://blog.sharepointsite.co.uk/2010/08/reusable-content-in-sp2010-issue.html)

Any workarounds?

Comment: According to that very article, it states that reusable content only works for field controls.  Is there any way that you can use that instead of a web part?

Comment: Can you describe it more vividly?

Comment: Field controls are defined in a page layout and map to the individual fields of the underlying content type.  It allows direct editing of content in the page without the use of Web Parts.

Comment: @Dave Wise: You could put your comments in an answer instead to get some rep. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dave has a point:

The workaround is to create custom layout based on the custom content type which itself is based on the publishing page content type. Also you have to add a new column of type "Full HTML content with formatting and constraints for publishing". You can add several depending on your needs. Then you can edit the custom layout in SP designer and add already defined custom content fields there

Answer (score 1):

This bug has been fixed in the June Cumulative Update:
http://sergeluca.wordpress.com/2011/09/06/reeusable-content-bug-fixed-in-the-june-cu/

I also verified this myself. I can now add reusable content and web parts within the same publishing field.